# Zoom não acontece corretamente ao carregar página ElevateZoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, zoom

Quando abro a página com o plugin `elevateZoom` **(plugin para dar zoom em imagem passando o mouse)** ele exibe normalmente as imagens de acordo com o que tem que ser, mas o problema começa quando passo o mouse na primeira imagem. O box do zoom dela carrega a imagem e não o zoom.

Por exemplo, quando passa o mouse em uma imagem tem que exibir o box com a imagem aumentada. Mas está acontecendo de a imagem que serve para o zoom aparecer dentro do box.

Para não acontecer isso eu tenho que clicar na miniatura da imagem, que fica na navegação.

**HTML**

```
<img id="img_01" src="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/238x424_49f0626340b6b5a8c878563458111b8e.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/238x424_49f0626340b6b5a8c878563458111b8e.jpg"/>
<div id="gal1">
<a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/238x424_49f0626340b6b5a8c878563458111b8e.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/854x1280_49f0626340b6b5a8c878563458111b8e.jpg"> <img id="img_01" src="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/67x100_49f0626340b6b5a8c878563458111b8e.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/238x424_b73b03fb99499385c994f506bd1569a8.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/854x1280_b73b03fb99499385c994f506bd1569a8.jpg"> <img id="img_01" src="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/67x100_b73b03fb99499385c994f506bd1569a8.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/238x424_78ce1f0dc3f35cfe611e438b0559ca59.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/854x1280_78ce1f0dc3f35cfe611e438b0559ca59.jpg"> <img id="img_01" src="http://localhost/CotasAlteracao/Andre/uploads/shop/67x100_78ce1f0dc3f35cfe611e438b0559ca59.jpg" /> </a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#img_01").elevateZoom({gallery:'gal1', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: "active", imageCrossfade: true, loadingIcon: "http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif"});

$("#img_01").bind("click", function(e) {
  var ez =   $('#img_01').data('elevateZoom');
  ez.closeAll(); //NEW: This function force hides the lens, tint and window
  $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
  return false;
});

});
</script>
```